# jQuery.Deferred() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I'm trying to implement indexedDB. For that I need to use `$.Deferred` to get the status of database creation. But the problem is, `Differed` is not working as expected.
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjcm49b/1/), you can find the process in the console.

And here is the code:

```js
$(function($) {
  var table = 'price';
  $.when(dbConnection('cw', table)).done(function(db) {
    console.log(db);
    var data = [];
    dbInsert(db, data, table);
  });

  function dbConnection(dbname, table) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
      // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
      var db = request.result;
      var store = db.createObjectStore(table, {
        keyPath: "id"
      });
      var styleCode = store.createIndex("style_code", "style_code");
      var colorCode = store.createIndex("color_code", "color_code");
      var size = store.createIndex("size", "size");
      var price1 = store.createIndex("price1", "price1");
    };
    request.onsuccess = function() {
      db = request.result;
      console.log(request.result);
      dfd.resolve(db);
      return dfd.promise();
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.resolve(null);
      return dfd.promise();
    };
    request.onabort = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.resolve(null);
      return dfd.promise();
    };
  }

  function dbInsert(db, data, table) {
    var tx = db.transaction(table, "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore(table);
    $.each(data, function(i, rows) {
      var style = rows['style-code'],
        color = rows['color-code'],
        size = rows['size'],
        price = rows['price1'];
      store.put({
        id: i,
        style_code: style,
        color_code: color,
        size: size,
        price1: price
      });
    });
    tx.oncomplete = function() {
      console.log('Data inserted successfully.');
    };
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Whether I'm doing anything wrong? or am I missing anything in this code?. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Why the downvote? This question provides everything needed to solve it (including JSFiddle). +1

Comment: Down voters, Please make mind to comment the reason for the downvote.....

Comment: Note: You should really use `reject` for the two error cases, unless you actually want to proceed with a `null` db.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Yes I should. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Have updated to cover that. Enjoy your promises :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting `dbConnection` to return a `promise`, but do not return *anything* from that function. Return the promise immediately (last line below) and not inside all the callbacks:

```
function dbConnection(dbname, table) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
      // The database did not previously exist, so create object stores and indexes.
      var db = request.result;
      var store = db.createObjectStore(table, {
        keyPath: "id"
      });
      var styleCode = store.createIndex("style_code", "style_code");
      var colorCode = store.createIndex("color_code", "color_code");
      var size = store.createIndex("size", "size");
      var price1 = store.createIndex("price1", "price1");
    };
    request.onsuccess = function() {
      db = request.result;
      console.log(request.result);
      dfd.resolve(db);
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.resolve(null);
    };
    request.onabort = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.resolve(null);
    };
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9kjcm49b/2/

Your various callbacks simply resolve or reject the deferred. The readonly promise returned earlier then triggers the next operation.

Note: You should probably use `reject` for the two error cases (unless you actually want to proceed with a null db value). e.g.

```
    request.onerror = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.reject("Error occurred");
    };
    request.onabort = function() {
      report(request.error);
      console.log(request.error);
      dfd.reject("Operation aborted");
    };
```

and use like this:

```
  $.when(dbConnection('cw', table)).done(function(db) {
    console.log(db);
    var data = [];
    dbInsert(db, data, table);
  }).fail(function(message){
         alert(message);
  });
```